# Schema.org structure for a news aggregator individual post

Tags: html5, microdata

I'm building a news aggregator website. This is my current schema structure for a single news article. There can be more than one article per page. I'm trying to have every possible piece of data structured. Am I missing something? How can this structure be schema.org-optimized for a news article post?

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">
    <meta itemprop="inLanguage" content="es-419" />
    <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2015-03-02T19:03Z" />
    <meta itemprop="keywords" content="correa, obama, whitehouse" />
    <meta itemprop="commentCount" content="41" />
    <meta itemprop="description" content="Excerpt of the news text goes here..." />
    <meta itemprop="isBasedOnUrl" content="http://eluniverso.com/2015/03/01/noticia3.html" />

    <h2 itemprop="headline">
        <a href="/noticias/2015/02/03/headline-goes-here" itemprop="url">Headline goes here</a>
    </h2>

    <time datetime="2015-03-02T17:43Z" itemprop="datePublished">Mar 2</time>
    <p itemprop="articleBody">Complete article goes here. Two or three lines perhaps. Maybe more.</p>
    <span class="tag" itemprop="articleSection">politics</span>
    <span class="length" itemprop="wordCount">67</span>

    <img src="uploads/image_4.jpg" itemprop="thumbnailUrl">

    <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">
        <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
        <span itemprop="ratingValue">4.1</span>/5 based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">249</span> votes
    </div>

    <span class="source" itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        <meta itemprop="logo" content="/logos/eluniverso.png" />
        <span itemprop="name">
            <a href="http://eluniverso.com/2015/03/01/example1.html">El Universo</a>
        </span>
    </span>
</article>

<ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <li><a href="/noticias/2015/02/01/original-breaking-news.html" itemprop="relatedLink">Related News 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/noticias/2015/02/02/more-data.html" itemprop="relatedLink">Related News 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/noticias/2015/02/03/other-thing-that-happened.html" itemprop="relatedLink">Related News 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### HTML5+Microdata

- In case of `meta`/`link`:

  If the value is a URI, you [have to use `link` instead of `meta`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669).

  So this

  ```
  <meta itemprop="isBasedOnUrl" content="http://eluniverso.com/2015/03/01/noticia3.html" />
  ```

  should be

  ```
  <link itemprop="isBasedOnUrl" href="http://eluniverso.com/2015/03/01/noticia3.html" />
  ```

  and this

  ```
  <meta itemprop="logo" content="/logos/eluniverso.png" />
  ```

  should be

  ```
  <link itemprop="logo" href="/logos/eluniverso.png" />
  ```
- Your thumbnail `img` is missing the required `alt` attribute.

#### Schema.org

- In addition to (or instead of) [`headline`](http://schema.org/headline) it can be beneficial to provide [`name`](http://schema.org/name). The `headline` property can only be used for `CreativeWork` (and sub-types), while the `name` property is defined for every type. It’s likely that many consumers look for and make use of `name` but not `headline`.

  You could provide both properties, [separated with a space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14216506/1591669), on the same element, i.e.,

  ```
  <h2 itemprop="headline name">
  ```
- If the link in `Organization` is about this organization, you might want to use the `url` property.
- The `WebPage` could reference the `NewsArticle` via the [`mainEntity` property](http://schema.org/mainEntity) (if the page is only about a single news article; otherwise the `NewsArticle` could reference its `WebPage` with the reverse [`mainEntityOfPage` property](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage)).

  While you could use Microdata’s `itemref` attribute to reference it without changing the markup structure, it’s not necessary if markup changes are possible. You could specify `WebPage` on a container `div` (or the `body`, if it’s the only/current web page), e.g.:

  ```
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

    <!-- properties about the web page, i.e., the web page’s URL -->

    <article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">

      <!-- properties about the news article, i.e., the news article’s URL -->

    </article>

    <ul>
      <li><a itemprop="relatedLink" href="/noticias/2015/02/01/original-breaking-news.html">Related News 1</a></li>
      <li><a itemprop="relatedLink" href="/noticias/2015/02/02/more-data.html">Related News 2</a></li>
      <li><a itemprop="relatedLink" href="/noticias/2015/02/03/other-thing-that-happened.html">Related News 3</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  ```

Comment: Great feedback! Yes, the link in `Organization` is from this organization, I can change it to `<link href="http://eluniverso.com">` - but then where can I put the original URI content? (This is a news aggregator service, I have to specify where the original content is)

Comment: Also, one last question, didn't even know how to structure it in my original post: How can I specify a list of related links inside the `NewsArticle` structure? Or should I make a separate `<div>` sibling with a `WebPage` schema?

Comment: @andufo: Ah, I misunderstood the link in `Organization`. Yes, you could add a `link` element with `url` property, pointing to the organization’s home page (but you don’t have to). -- How to reference the original URL of the article, that’s a good question … the `Organization` item would not be the correct place for this, as this is directly related to the `NewsArticle`, not the publisher of it. Actually, it would be the `url` of the `NewsArticle`, but I guess there’s a conflict of interest as you want to provide your own URL here. Maybe [`sameAs`](http://schema.org/sameAs)? Not sure.

Comment: got it! for my 2nd (and last question) I edited the original code by adding that `WebPage` structure separated from the `NewsArticle` structure. Is that alright? Any way to actually put `WebPage` **inside** of `NewsArticle`?

Comment: @andufo: `NewsArticle` does not offer a property for related links. Using `WebPage` and its [`relatedLink` property](http://schema.org/relatedLink) would be a solution, yes. You could then use [`about`](http://schema.org/about) (and maybe [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity)) to reference the `NewsArticle`. In that case, you might even give the `WebPage` your `url`, and the `NewsArticle` the `url` of the original publisher … maybe.

Comment: thanks! I updated the original post to match all your recommendations. If you can check the update, that would be great, so I know I implemented everything as you said. Two things: 1) I ended up using my own url for both NewsArticle and WebPage (is that alright?) 2) Also, I had no idea on how to reference `NewsArticle` with `mainEntity`. Tried to search for examples but it's not quite clear. Care to elaborate further? :)

Comment: @andufo: I updated my answer based on your original snippet with the added `WebPage`. Regarding your "FINAL STRUCTURE UPDATE": as far as I know, here on Code Review you should not update your question with an updated snippet that implements the feedback you got so far. If, after you’ve implemented any feedback etc., you still wonder if anything can be improved, you could create a new question with the updated markup. So I’d suggest to rollback your last edit, so that all users that might add an answer here base it on your original code.

Comment: duly noted :) sorry this is my 1st post here, i was mainly a SO user before. I'll remove it asap, thanks again for everything!